# PhpStorm: Can't push anymore with push window (Log In to GitHub)

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

When I use the push window

[image]

And I klick on Push, suddenly a popup comes.

[image]

When I successfully log in using the button in the popup

[image]

I still receive the login popup after trying to push again

[image]

But when I use the terminal with the same github user, and push on the same repository, it works.

[image]

So it seems that the user has write access. But what should I do so that pushing with the push window works again?

**EDIT**

In the event log, there are `Repository not found` errors, but when I go to the URL, I can see the repository.

```
09:39   Push failed
        remote: Repository not found.
        Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/..bla...git/'
```

Comment: There are couple of things two check:
1. Do you have "use credential helper" enabled under Preferences | Version Control | Git? If yes, please disable it and try again.
2. Otherwise, there could be an issue from OAuth side, please follow:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404416401042-Operations-Against-a-GitHub-Repository-Are-Failing

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov 1) "Use credential helper" was not checked, so I leave it unchecked. 2) I will look at the resources when I have the time. But since the PhpStorm page says "..successfully authorized ..", **and** pushing over the terminal works, I would expect that it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: "Repository not found" is a generic error message that can be thrown in case when you are trying to perform git operations against organization's repository and no access has been granted to IDE as it's mentioned here:
https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-your-membership-in-organizations/requesting-organization-approval-for-oauth-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be happened since my coworker setted up github `teams`, where my account is connected.

At the end my solution was to change the remote url `https` variant, to the `ssh` variant.

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[repo-owner-username]/[repo-name].git`

Now pushing over PhpStorm with the push window works again.